# VBA Word: remove editing restriction at opening and restrict again when closing

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to set a macro that would trigger each time I open a word document and check if it has an editing restriction. If so, try password from a list of passwords (hardcoded). In case one password is successfull, keep it in memory, remove restriction, and re-apply the restriction when I close the document.

In this way, if I always use the same password for the documents I use and restrict, I could open them on my computer as if there was no restriction, but the restriction would still apply to other users.

Note: the macro in Private Sub Document_Open() would need to trigger on all documents I open from my computer only. Documents must be .docx and not .docm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note 1: You will need to put this into a .dotm file and ultimately save as a global template on your PC (google).

Note 2: This will fail if you open more than 1 doc because only 1 password is stored - you could write the password as a document property (which you would retrieve & delete before saving and relocking).

Depending on whether or not you are happy to add code to the Normal.dotm template (personally I'm not) will influence how you do this.

If NOT using Normal.dotm then you will need to setup a global template AND trigger the code by creating your own application events as described here: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/PseudoAutoMacros.htm

If using Normal.dotm then in `ThisDocument` add:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Name
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
    unlocker oDoc
End Sub
```

And (for testing) in a regular module add the following (you'll likely want to split this into separate units of code later):

```
Sub unlocker(ByVal docToUnlock As Document)
    If Not docToUnlock.Type = wdTypeDocument Then
        ' this is a template, don't try anything
        MsgBox "Not a doc"
        GoTo endOfSub
        Else
        MsgBox "Is a doc"
    End If


    Dim passWords() As String
    passWords = Split("pw1,pw2,pw3", ",")

    Dim iLoop As Long
    iLoop = LBound(passWords)

    On Error GoTo err_Test:
    
    Do While Not ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection
        If iLoop > UBound(passWords) Then Exit Do
    
        oldpassword = passWords(iLoop)

        ActiveDocument.Unprotect oldpassword
        iLoop = iLoop + 1
    Loop

    If Not ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
        ' unable to unlock document, quit
        oldpassword = vbNullString
        MsgBox "Failed to Unlock"
        GoTo endOfSub
    Else
        MsgBox "Unlocked"
    End If

    ' Do Stuff

    If Not oldpassword = vbNullString Then
        ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading, Password:=oldpassword
    End If

endOfSub:
    Exit Sub

err_Test:
    If Err.Number = 5485 Then
        ' ignore error due to wrong password
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    Else
        ' handle unexpected error
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear SlowLearner, thank you for your answer.
I placed this code in ThisDocument of Normal.dotm. I can see this code is now accessible from all .docx documents. I use word 2016. When opening a restricted document, I have to click on View, Edit document. `Private Sub Document_Open()` do not trigger. If I enter to vba editor and press F5 the sub works correctly and remove the protection as expected. What is missing ?

Comment: So it works for proteced documents but not for documents opened in protected view (i.e downloaded or opened from network?

Comment: I created 2 new documents on my desktop. The first one without restriction, and the second one with restriction. `Private Sub Document_Open()` triggers only when I open the unrestricted document.
I also tried to create `Private Sub AutoExec()` in a separate module of Normal.dotm. It is not triggering either.

Comment: Ok I have made some changes to the code (view question edit history to see changes if you like), basically added message boxes and changed the way a document is passed - now passed as an object.  Have tested with Normal.dotm and seems to work for me. Please test and let me know :)

Comment: I see all the msgboxes when I open the unrestricted document, however it is still not triggering when I open the restricted document. When I open a restricted document in Word 2016, I can see the document content, but I can't edit it and the ribbon do not load. There are only File, Tools, and View available. I need to click on View then Edit Document in order to open the document and see the ribbon loaded. Maybe it is a problem with word 2016?

Comment: Might be, but I am not certain what exactly you mean by 'restricted'... (see my previous comment) as a workaround you could try to add a button to the QAT as outlined here. Cheers,

Comment: May I send you my document in PM so you could see if it is working for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157217/discussion-between-slowlearner-and-user3019338).

Comment: I had a second template different from Normal.dotm, this was the problem. I created new documents, from Normal.dotm, applied the restriction, and your code works just fine. 
Thank you SlowLearner for your support!

Comment: No worries, feel fee to press the up arrow next to the question :)